# how to disable WP7 MapPolyline auto background painting?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, bing-maps

Like the Title says, Is there a way to disable bing's map auto background painting every time a new point is discovered?

constructor :

```
            bFirstPointRecv = true;
            polyline = new MapPolyline();          
            polyline.Fill = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
            polyline.Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
            polyline.StrokeThickness = 5;
            polyline.Opacity = 0.4;
            polyline.Locations = MapManager.MapMgr.mCoordinates;
            map1.Children.Add(polyline);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake was that i used the FILL property.. I simplly had to remove that initializtion line

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. I would recommend you hook into the [MapCore.ViewChangeStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.core.mapcore.viewchangestart%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and [MapCore.ViewChangeEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.core.mapcore.viewchangeend%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) events.

Then you can perform calculations, and then set the values to your poly-line at the view-end event, to avoid rendering more than once.

I use it for filtering items based on the current area (which you can get with the [MapCore.ViewportPointToLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.viewportpointtolocation.aspx) method, along with the [MapMode.ViewportSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.core.mapmode.viewportsize%28v=vs.92%29.aspx))